# PHP - Get maximum key and its value in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a for each loop that loops through a set of dates. How can I get the max value of `$key_date`?

```
    $i=0;
    foreach ($data as $key_date => $value_price) 
    {  
        if($key_date>=$start_date && $key_date<=$end_date) 
        {
            if (empty($temp[$i])) {
                $temp[$i]=array($key_date(float)$value_price['price']);
             }
            else {
                 array_push($temp[$i], (float)$value_price['price']);
                 }
              $i++;
        }  
    }
```

Right now i get all the key_dates and value_prices based on the start and end date.How can I get only the price based on the latest date (max date). So instead of doing

```
array_push($temp[$i], (float)$value_price['settlement_price']);
```

I should be able to do array_push latest date between the $start_date and $end_date and its correspnding price

Comment: Do you have sample data please?

Comment: From where do you get your data?

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php, there is an example with DateTime objects.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324165/if-next-item-in-looping-array-exists#answer-12324220) answer if valuable for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the maximum key in an array you can use:

`$max_key = max(array_keys($array));`

You can look here for more details:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php